# React+to get file details with name,type, and binary data and all details well sufficient for backend sysytem to store image

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

Guys am doing a drag and drop file upload. I have done almost and am to retrieve file name. but am doubtful what exactly i need to send to backend to store image . With the same i need to send video or pdf as well.. Also preview also will be hlepful. Can you help.. here is the code i tried

DragAndDrop.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class DragAndDrop extends Component {
  state = {
    drag: false
  };
  dropRef = React.createRef();
  handleDrag = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  };
  handleDragIn = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.dragCounter++;
    if (e.dataTransfer.items && e.dataTransfer.items.length > 0) {
      this.setState({ drag: true });
    }
  };
  handleDragOut = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.dragCounter--;
    if (this.dragCounter === 0) {
      this.setState({ drag: false });
    }
  };
  handleDrop = e => {
    console.log("e", e);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({ drag: false });
    if (e.dataTransfer.files && e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
      this.props.handleDrop(e.dataTransfer.files);
      e.dataTransfer.clearData();
      this.dragCounter = 0;
    }
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    let div = this.dropRef.current;
    div.addEventListener("dragenter", this.handleDragIn);
    div.addEventListener("dragleave", this.handleDragOut);
    div.addEventListener("dragover", this.handleDrag);
    div.addEventListener("drop", this.handleDrop);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    let div = this.dropRef.current;
    div.removeEventListener("dragenter", this.handleDragIn);
    div.removeEventListener("dragleave", this.handleDragOut);
    div.removeEventListener("dragover", this.handleDrag);
    div.removeEventListener("drop", this.handleDrop);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ display: "inline-block", position: "relative" }}
        ref={this.dropRef}
      >
        {this.state.dragging && (
          <div
            style={{
              border: "dashed grey 4px",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,.8)",
              position: "absolute",
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              zIndex: 9999
            }}
          >
            <div
              style={{
                position: "absolute",
                top: "50%",
                right: 0,
                left: 0,
                textAlign: "center",
                color: "grey",
                fontSize: 36
              }}
            >
              <div>drop here :)</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default DragAndDrop;
```

MyComponent.js

```
import Modal from "react-modal";
import { Player } from "video-react";
import "./styles.css";
import AutoFill from "./data";
import DragAndDrop from "./DragAndDrop";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      modalIsOpen: false,
      files: []
}
}
handleDrop = files => {
    console.log(files);
    let fileList = this.state.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (!files[i].name) return;
      fileList.push(files[i].webkitRelativePath );
    }
    this.setState({ files: fileList });
  };
render(
return{
<div>
          <DragAndDrop handleDrop={this.handleDrop}>
            <div className="dropHolder" style={{ height: 300, width: 250 }}>
              {this.state.files.map(file => (
                <div key={file}>{file}</div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </DragAndDrop>
</div>
})
export default App
```

Guys can you help me with what all i need to send to backend for file upload (rite now am getting filename and also type and size am getting),but as per my understanding binary/multipart data is needed. how can i get that also pdf and video need to be uploaded ,possible preview of the image also will be helpful.

Any working demo or fiddle will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way of both normal file upload and drag and drop file upload

```
https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/react-file-upload-proper-server-side-nodejs-easy/
```